# Use a background color for the screen between pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a project where my client asked me if I could eliminate the white flash, shown while switching pages. Now obviously this seems fairly impossible, since this is just the transition between two pages.

Normally I'd use AJAX to solve this problem, however, I'm working in an existing Wordpress codebase, and I'd like to use the most simple solution, so preferably something like making it look like the loading screen is e.g. black by loading the background color first, before the rest of the stuff on the page.

Is this a possibility, and if it is, does anyone know how to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: so you don't want a full sized loading screen which will fade out after page loads?

Comment: I don't think this can be done without altering the browser css (like Custom.css for chrome).

Answer (score 2):

You have to build your website like a one-page app.

You create a layout page with your theme and you load your page content in ajax.
In this way, there won't be any reloading.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this code

```js
window.onload = function () { 
    var spinner = document.getElementById("loaderWrapper");
    spinner.setAttribute('style', 'opacity:0;transition: 1.5s linear;');
    setTimeout(function(){
        spinner.style.display = "none";
    },500);
}
```

```css
.content{
width: 500px;
height: 300px;
background: red;}
#loaderWrapper{
 position: fixed;
 top:0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: black;
 text-align: center;
 z-index: 100; 
 opacity: 1;
}
#loaderWrapper:after{
    content: "Loading...";
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}
.loader {
 border: 3px solid #f3f3f3;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border-top: 3px solid #3498db;
 width: 45px;
 height: 45px;
 -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
 animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
 margin-top: 30%;
    margin-top: 50vh;
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div id="loaderWrapper"><div class="loader"></div></div>
<div class="content">COntent here</div>
```